# Faulty avltree implementation c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

this is my current avltree implementation, avltree.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
namespace avltree {

    template <class T>
    struct node {
        static node * null_node;
        node *left = null_node;
        node *right = null_node;
        node *parent = null_node;
        int height = 0;
        T value;
        node(T value) :value(value) {}
        node(T value, int height) :height(height), value(value) {}
    };
    template <class T>
    node<T>* node<T>::null_node = new node(0, -1);

    template <class T>
    struct avltree {
    public:
        node<T> *root;
        avltree(T value);
        node<T> *insert(T value);
        void print(void);
        void print_with_height(void);
    private:
        node<T> *insert(T value, node<T> *x);
        node<T> *left_rotate(node<T> *x);
        node<T> *right_rotate(node<T> *x);
        void retrace(node<T> *n);
        void update_root();
        void print(node<T> *n);
        void print(node<T> *n, int depth);
        void update_height(node<T> *n);
    };
    template <class T>
    avltree<T>::avltree(T value) :root(new node<T>(value)) { }

    template <class T>
    node<T> *avltree<T>::insert(T value) {
        auto n = insert(value, root);
        update_root();
        return n;
    }
    template <class T>
    void avltree<T>::retrace(node<T> *n) {
        while (n != node<T>::null_node) {
            update_height(n);
            if (n->left->height - n->right->height > 1) {
                if (n->left->left->height >= n->left->right->height) {
                    right_rotate(n);
                }
                else {
                    left_rotate(n);
                    right_rotate(n);
                }
            }
            else
                if (n->right->height - n->left->height > 1) {
                    if (n->right->right->height >= n->right->left->height) {
                        left_rotate(n);
                    }
                    else {
                        right_rotate(n);
                        left_rotate(n);
                    }
            }
            n = n->parent;
        }
    }
    template <class T>
    node<T> *avltree<T>::insert(T value, node<T> *n) {
        if (n->value > value) {
            if (n->left != node<T>::null_node) {
                n->left->height++;
                insert(value, n->left);
            }
            else {
                auto new_node = new node<T>(value);
                n->left = new_node;
                new_node->parent = n;
                retrace(n);
                return new_node;
            }
        }
        if (n->value < value) {
            if (n->right != node<T>::null_node) {
                n->right->height++;
                insert(value, n->right);
            }
            else {
                auto new_node = new node<T>(value);
                n->right = new_node;
                new_node->parent = n;
                retrace(n);
                return new_node;
            }
        }
        update_height(n);
        return n;
    }
    template <class T>
    node<T> *avltree<T>::left_rotate(node<T> *x) {
        node<T> *y = x->right;
        if (y == node<T>::null_node) {
            return node<T>::null_node;
        }
        y->parent = x->parent;
        if (x->parent->right == x) {
            x->parent->right = y;
        }
        else {
            x->parent->left = y;
        }

        y->left = x;
        x->parent = y;

        x->right = y->left;
        x->right->parent = x;

        update_height(x);
        update_height(y);

        return x;
    }
    template <class T>
    node<T> *avltree<T>::right_rotate(node<T> *x) {
        node<T> *y = x->left;
        if (y == node<T>::null_node) {
            return node<T>::null_node;
        }
        y->parent = x->parent;
        if (x->parent->right == x) {
            x->parent->right = y;
        }
        else {
            x->parent->left = y;
        }

        y->right = x;
        x->parent = y;

        x->left = y->right;
        x->left->parent = x;

        update_height(x);
        update_height(y);

        return x;
    }
    template <class T>
    void avltree<T>::update_root() {
        auto n = root, last = root;
        while (n != node<T>::null_node) {
            last = n;
            n = n->parent;
        }
        root = last;
    }
    template <class T>
    void avltree<T>::print(void) {
        print(root);
        cout << endl;
    }
    template <class T>
    void avltree<T>::print(node<T> *n) {
        if (n->left != node<T>::null_node) {
            print(n->left);
        }
        cout << n->value << " ";
        if (n->right != node<T>::null_node) {
            print(n->right);
        }
    }
    template <class T>
    void avltree<T>::print(node<T> *n, int height) {
        if (n->left != node<T>::null_node) {
            print(n->left, height);
        }
        if (n->height == height) {
            std::cout << n->value << ", ";
        }
        if (n->right != node<T>::null_node) {
            print(n->right, height);
        }
    }
    template <class T>
    void avltree<T>::print_with_height(void) {
        int height = root->height;
        for (int height = root->height; height >= 0; height--) {
            std::cout << "height = " << height << "\t:";
            print(root, height);
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    template <class T>
    void avltree<T>::update_height(node<T> *n) {
        n->height = std::max(n->left->height, n->right->height) + 1;
    }
}
```

And the following is main file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "avltree.h"

int main()
{
    avltree::avltree<int> tree(1);
    for (int i = 2; i < 128; i++) {
        tree.insert(i);
    }
    tree.print_with_height();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem with above code is that at iteration 124 it will generate an infinite loop inside retrace call in insert. Basically, the nodes will keep being rotated in such a way that root node cannot be reached (resulting in an infinite loop). I have checked the trivial examples (for a few nodes) and they work. Everything for a run is provided, I would appreciate if someone with experience in avltrees could take their time and run this program, perhaps finding out what goes wrong inside retrace/rotations.

Comment: If you can reliably replicate the bug at a specific point in time (when `i == 124` for example) then you can stop execution at that point inside a debugger, and step through your code line by line to see what happens and what the problem might be. [Please learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You have a plan in mind.  You know where the code goes wrong.  Start debugging where the code goes wrong, i.e. where it goes against the plan you had.  If the original plan has a flaw, then redo the plan and then recode.  Never write a full program with only a portion of knowing exactly what you should be doing, and then hopefully figure out the rest by moving or introducing variables and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting an infinite loop like that indicates a likely problem with your rotate functions.  A quick look at `left_rotate` shows

```
    y->left = x;
    x->parent = y;

    x->right = y->left;
```

What is `y->left` in that last assignment?  `x`, so what you're really is `x->right = x`.  This is clearly a problem that needs to be fixed.

A similar problem exists in `right_rotate`.